# Android Webview "Uncaught storage unavailable" trying to load Google News url

Tags: android, webview

When I try to load the url https://news.google.com/news?edchanged=1&ned=us#3 in a WebView nothing loads & I get the bellow errors in LogCat and and in the Chrome inspector. But if I load http://www.google.com and then navigate to the news site it works just fine.

```
mWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.news_webview);
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("https://news.google.com/news?edchanged=1&ned=us#3");
```

Errors

```
"Uncaught storage unavailable", source: https://ssl.gstatic.com/news-static/js/2240668624-en-phoneapp_tier0_cssrename_phoneappmanager_tier0.js (41)

"Powered by AMP ⚡ HTML – Version 1477334765771", source: https://cdn.ampproject.org/rtv/031477334765771/v0.js (341)
```